# What is needed to be able to make a backup of mongo database

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to make a backup of mongo database, but I keep getting authentication errors.
I gave my user all the privileges I could and I still cannot do a backup:

```
# mongosh --host 10.1.10.1 --port 27017 -u administrator admin --quiet --eval "db.getUsers();"
Enter password: ************************************
{
  users: [
    {
      _id: 'admin.administrator',
      userId: UUID("52befffa-7fa9-4ab9-9325-3dfdead28f20"),
      user: 'administrator',
      db: 'admin',
      roles: [
        { role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' },
        { role: 'restore', db: 'admin' },
        { role: 'readWriteAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' },
        { role: 'root', db: 'admin' },
        { role: 'backup', db: 'admin' }
      ],
      mechanisms: [ 'SCRAM-SHA-1', 'SCRAM-SHA-256' ]
    },
    {
      _id: 'admin.project-12',
      userId: UUID("375a91b7-8c27-4d1d-8d02-ba04faaa94ce"),
      user: 'project-12',
      db: 'admin',
      roles: [ { role: 'readWrite', db: 'project-12' } ],
      mechanisms: [ 'SCRAM-SHA-1', 'SCRAM-SHA-256' ]
    }
  ],
  ok: 1
}
```

```
# mongodump --host 10.1.10.1 --port 27017 -u administrator --archive=test-1 --db=project-12
Enter password:

2022-05-12T18:01:55.677+0200    Failed: can't create session: could not connect to server: connection() error occured during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to specify the authentication database

Comment: It worked, thanks. Write it as an answer and I will accept it.
Also why `mongosh` is using `admin` as default auth database and `mongodump` is using something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the authentication database, for example

```
mongodump --host 10.1.10.1 --port 27017 -u administrator --authenticationDatabase=admin ...
```

On `mongosh` the authentication database defaults to the database you connect. See [Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470)